# Win 8.1 setup program cannot any drive attached to my computer even I see them on Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I try to install Win8.1 with a bootable USB. When I boot the PC with the Win8.1 DVD and select the Install Now option at the drive list there is no recognized drive to install OS even there are one HDD and one SSD attached the computer. I can see them in Ubuntu Live CD Gparted program. I also tried diskpart in Win 8.1, however when I run `list disk` it shows the drives but the status is `No Media`.

I also tried to format these drives to NTFS by Ubuntu with msdos and gpt partition tables. However no result I got.

Any suggestion for installing Win 8.1 by solving explained problem?

Comment: Are you installing in BIOS or UEFI mode? Also check whether AHCI mode is selected in the BIOS/UEFI. If it is, try switching to IDE instead and see if the drives are detected.

Comment: UEFI. And what is the difference btw AHCI and IDE ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/337619/sata-drives-what-is-the-difference-b-w-ide-mode-and-ahci

Comment: I just see that it is RAID

Comment: So you have a RAID setup? Which [level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels)?

Comment: it is only written RAID in BIOS. I am not sure. I changed it to AHCI but still same problem. I will try IDE. However, why win 8 does not support AHCI even it is better.

Comment: Who says it doesn't support AHCI? Vista onwards supports it out of the box as the answer I linked to states. Probably some weird stuff going on with your setup (motherboard).

Comment: IDE does not work too

Comment: Edit your question and include all relevant hardware details; especially regarding the motherboard. I assume you're attempting to install on the SSD? Try disconnecting the HDD in that case. If the SSD doesn't show up try connecting only the HDD and see if that shows up instead. Also try connecting them to different SATA ports on the motherboard.

Comment: As @Karen suggested, you need to specify your motherboard. Chances are you do not have the drivers for your motherboard's SATA controller and need to download it from the manufacturer's website