# Windows 10 not accepting AHCI enabled, why?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, ahci

My notebook has a ordinary 500GB HDD boot with Windows 10 and a small SSD onboard (24GB) that I intent to use as cache (since Samsung has discontinued ExpressCache). I have to change some settings and I saw AHCI option in BIOS setup: Auto/Manual and Manual can be Enabled/Disabled.

The only combination that works is Manual, Disabled. Otherwise Windows 10 stops in a blue screen - inaccessible device error.

Is this AHCI good for me? How can I make Windows 10 boot with AHCI enabled in this case?

Comment: Reinstall Windows, providing the AHCI driver during the initial setup.

Comment: And do you think is better with AHCI enabled for best performance? Why people keep down voting everything in this forum? Is this a stupid question? I have seen good questions being down voted, this practice will decrease participation!

Comment: "And do you think is better with AHCI enabled for best performance?"  Don't you? Why are you trying to enable it if you don't know if/why you want it?   As for the down-vote, I'd guess it's due to a lack of research effort shown, as turning on AHCI after Windows is already installed had been covered here in the past.

Comment: [SATA drives: What is the difference b/w IDE mode and AHCI?](http://superuser.com/questions/337619/sata-drives-what-is-the-difference-b-w-ide-mode-and-ahci)

Comment: [Change from IDE to AHCI after installing Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/471102/change-from-ide-to-ahci-after-installing-windows-8), [How can I enable AHCI on a SATA drive after installing Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/110927/how-can-i-enable-ahci-on-a-sata-drive-after-installing-windows), etc. :)

Comment: Make and model of laptop?

Comment: It's a Samsung Ultrabook Series 5 (530U3C-AD2). I give a call to support, but they don't support Windows 10, I am on my on. @TECHIE007: the point is to understand AHCI, not just to change, spending efforts without knowing if will have some benefits.